# NodeJS API with DynamoDB - Missing region in config but it is set

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb

I created a NodeJS API and when I start my server, I can do my HTTP requests with success to my AWS Dynamo DB. But about twenty seconds after the request's response, the server crashes and says "missing region in config"

My requests are successful so why does it do that ?

This is my `server.js` :

```
const express = require('express');
const config = require('./config');
const cors = require('cors');
const createError = require('http-errors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

// parse requests
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

//Enable CORS for all HTTP methods
app.use(cors());

// Routes
require('./routes/survey.route.js')(app);
require('./routes/user.route.js')(app);

// Handle defaut request without any route or params
app.get('/', (request, response) => {
     response.send("Welcome to my API !");
});

// Listen on port 8080 for connections
app.listen(config.serverPort, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.log('something bad happened', err);
    }

    console.log(`server is listening on ${config.serverPort}`);
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req);
    next(createError(404));
});
module.exports = app;
```

Each of my routes' requests include the file `database.js`

Which has code :

```
// Configuring the database
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const config = require('./config');

AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: config.aws_accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: config.aws_secretAccessKey,
    region: config.aws_region
});
```

And this is my `config.js` :

```
module.exports = {
    baseUrl: '/api',
    serverPort: 8080,
    aws_accessKeyId: 'XXXXX',
    aws_secretAccessKey: 'XXXXX',
    aws_region: "us-east-2"
};

module.exports = AWS;
```

I can't find why my app crashes in both local and EC2 instance...

Haven't been able to fix this since few days of searches

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by creating a new project from scratch and deleting dynamoose